# How to remove the Orbeon forms appearance of repeated grid's Insert drop-down

Tags: orbeon

Can i Know how to remove the Appearance of repeated grids drop-down option. I have used bellow code, but it will remove '+' button also, what i need is keeping the '+' button and remove only the drop-down in repeated grid.

```
<property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.xforms.xbl.fr.grid.appearance.*.*"
    value="minimal"/>
```

[image: The drop-down need to be remove]

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, you can use the [minimal repeat appearance](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/grid#minimal-repeat-appearance), which doesn't have that dropdown, but if you want to use the [full repeat appearance](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/grid#full-repeat-appearance), there is at this point no configuration for you to just remove the dropdown.

So instead, I would recommend doing this with [custom CSS](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/styling/css) that hides the dropdown.

Comment: Noted. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome @MaheshHapuarachchige, and I hope this technique will work for you. If not, of course, just let me know.